# ¿Cómo concatenar una string dentro de la instrucción de un ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular

Suponiendo que en mi component.ts tengo una variable `valor: string = 'jal';`y quiero utilizarla dentro de la declaración de un ngfor

```
<option *ngFor="let tienda of tiendas.valor">
```

¿Cómo puedo concatenar la variable en la declaración de mi ngFor para que quedé así?

```
<option *ngFor="let tienda of tiendas.jal">
```

Comment: has probado con `<option *ngFor="let tienda of tiendas[string]">`?

Comment: @Naimad tu comentario en sí es la respuesta adecuada, podrías moverlo a una nueva respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta sería la siguiente:
`<option *ngFor="let tienda of tiendas[string]">`
Tiendas es un obj, y por tanto podemos acceder a sus propiedades de esa forma mediante su key.

Ej:

```
var x = “attr1”;
var Obj = {attr1: 1, attr2:2}
//obj[x] nos devolverá 1
```

Comment: puedes explicar un poco más el por qué sería la forma correcta?

Answer (score 0):

Como comenta @Naimad una opción en el ngFor sería usar la siguiente sintaxis

`objeto[propiedad: string]: any`

Accediendo así a cada propiedad de este.

**Nota** no se debe confundir con un indice literal como por ejemplo pasa con PHP.

En mi opinión no se debería usar este tipo de expresiones dentro de un template. En su lugar usar una funcion para la obtencion.

`<option *ngFor="let tienda of tiendasSeleccionadas">`

Siendo `tiendasSeleccionadas` una variable calculada previamente o susceptible de modificarse dentro de `ngOnchanges`, `ngOnInit` u otro evento.